# What is the role of public key token?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the role of public key token? Does it have any part in decrypting the signed hash. In GAC, why are there so many assemblies from Microsoft with the same public key token?

Comment: @Bombe, Decrypting a signing hash would be correct, only 1 error.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/573079/284795

Comment: If you're familiar with SSH or PGP, it's what you know as a fingerprint, ie. a shortened version of the public key that's easier to inspect by eye.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

> What is the role of public key token?

The public key token is a small number which is a convenient "token" representing a public key.  Public keys are quite long; the purpose of the public key token is to let you refer to keys without saying the whole key. Sort of the same way saying "The Lord of the Rings" is five words which *represent* a half-a-million-word novel. It would be rather inconvenient if every time you wanted to talk about it, you had to state those half-a-million words.

> Does it have any part in decrypting the signed hash?

No. The public key token has no "information" in it. It's just a number that *represents* a public key. It is not itself a public key.

> why are there so many assemblies from Microsoft with the same public key token?

Because they were all signed with the same private key -- Microsoft's private key -- and are therefore all verified with the same public key, and therefore all have the same public key token.

Comment: What a Crisp and Perfect answer Eric!

Comment: @Ammar via code check the [`Assembly.FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) property, to get it via command line tools see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3045089/80274)

Answer (score 15):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly)

"The public key token is used to make the assembly name unique. Thus, two strong named assemblies can have the same PE file name and yet .NET will recognize them as different assemblies. The Windows file system (FAT32 and NTFS) only recognizes the PE file name, so two assemblies with the same PE file name (but different culture, version or public key token) cannot exist in the same Windows folder. To solve this issue .NET introduces something called the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) which is treated as a single folder by the .NET CLR, but is actually implemented using nested NTFS (or FAT32) folders.

To prevent spoofing attacks, where a cracker would try to pass off an assembly appearing as something else, the assembly is signed with a private key. The developer of the intended assembly keeps the private key secret, so a cracker cannot have access to it nor simply guess it. Thus the cracker cannot make his assembly impersonate something else, lacking the possibility to correctly sign it after the change. Signing the assembly involves taking a hash of important parts of the assembly and then encrypting the hash with the private key. The signed hash is stored in the assembly along with the public key. **The public key will decrypt the signed hash.** When the CLR loads a strongly named assembly it will generate a hash from the assembly and then compare this with the decrypted hash. If the comparison succeeds then it means that the public key in the file (and hence the public key token) is associated with the private key used to sign the assembly. This will mean that the public key in the assembly is the public key of the assembly publisher and hence a spoofing attack is thwarted.
"

Answer (score 6):

The hash is kind of a "finger print". It is signed using a private key owned (and only known) by the signer. If you know the public key of the signer, you can check if the hash is really from the signer and thus if the data/file really originates from the signer (and is unchanged). 
Same public keys for some files in the GAC mean "all signed by the same signer".

Comment: so the token is just an indicator of the pub key used right? It doesn't participate directly in encryption/decryption

Answer (score 5):

The Public Key Token is a somewhat readable excerpt of the real public key. The complete public key is stored inside a signed assembly and is used to decrypt the signature (= encrypted hash). The loader uses this to verify the contents are not tampered with (or damaged). The original hash was encrypted by the author using a private key and only someone in possession of that key can produce a valid signature.

Each company (or department) should only use 1 key-pair, that is why you see groups of identical PKT's in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the previous answers (especially to the one with the quote from Wikipedia) that the strong naming via public/private key doesn't protect you from getting a changed assembly or prevent someone from tampering with your assemblies.

**First of all**, strong name doesn't guarantee that assembly can be trusted. You just have a public key/public key token, but you don't know the person who signed it (except if they somehow announce that they own the assemblies public key).

For example, the hacker could take yours assembly, remove strong name from it (there are tools which do it), and sign it with its own strong name. 
For the trust there is a different kind of digital code signing with the certificate. It involves third party checking you and your company and is not free. Check out Authenticode technology:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359(v=vs.85).aspx

**Secondly**, In the following discussion briefly described a brute force attack method to get public/private key pair with the same public key token which would produce the same hash for a tampered assembly:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/Jo6PqypxJN8

I must note that this could have been addressed by the enhanced strong naming
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/enhanced-strong-naming

There were also a bug mentioned in the discussion which allowed to skip the validation of assembly and load a tampered assembly at runtime. The detailed research is here, the bug was fixed in the later versions of .Net framework(so the bug present for the old .Net 1):

http://www.grimes.nildram.co.uk/workshops/fusionWSCrackThree.htm

**Thirdly**, starting the .Net 3.5 sp1 to increase the performance of the load of the assemblies are not validated by default for full trust assemblies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-disable-the-strong-name-bypass-feature

The condition for assemblies:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2008/05/14/strong-name-bypass/

The discussion about it on Stack Overflow:
[Are signed .net assemblies ever fully verified when loaded, to check they haven't been modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105103/are-signed-net-assemblies-ever-fully-verified-when-loaded-to-check-they-haven)

As I understand, this means that assembly is not hashed during load to check if it

**Lastly**, I would like to mention that there is a debate about pros and cons of strong naming since they require that you specify an assembly version. Microsoft removes strong name from some of their products:
https://www.pedrolamas.com/2016/03/01/still-strong-naming-your-assemblies-you-do-know-its-2016-right/

**In conclusion**, I wanted to summarize all of the mentioned points. When I encountered strong naming I was misguided by the MSDN and Wikipedia that it could provide some sort of defense for the assemblies. I thought "Cool" and the strong naming remained in my memory as a protection mechanism. Until the moment I had to think about the safety of my snk file with private key and then my colleague told me that it's not so "Cool". So I did a little research.
The first thing I learned was that strong name doesn't mean trust, you should use the certificate for it. 
Still, I thought that if I keep my private key safe then the tampered assembly won't be signed by me, meaning that if someone will modify my assembly then he has to modify the sign too and the modified assembly won't be loaded by the CLR. Now I don't think that strong naming guarantees that. So you should rely on it only to guarantee the uniqueness of the assembly.

PS. Sorry for the long post with a lot of references.