# Exception while accessing data through linq & entityframework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, wpf-controls

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The component 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_05FB87F8C316B6DF15988BC9D5490B22CB7A8FD7DD4DBD1126E065199C01A696' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/CRUDusingWPF;component/product.xaml'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The component does not have a resource identified by the uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646331/the-component-does-not-have-a-resource-identified-by-the-uri)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you have given enough info for others to help you.

Are you trying to use a DataTemplate for a Product?

Try turning off proxy creation and see if that makes a difference.

context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;