# What creates the directory "app.publish" in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

I switched over visual studio 2010 express, to visual studio 2013.
Now, whenever I try to test the code, he says /bin/release/app.publish access is denied, giving back a error and forcing me to manually delete the folder. Every single time.

Why is visual studio attempting to create that path in the first place? Whenever I go there he is empty anyways.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I was experimenting with ClickOnce, then decided against using it, then started noticing a `MyApp.application` file and `app.publish` folder in my bin directory. Unchecking "Enable ClickOnce security settings" on the Security tab did the trick for me.

[image: ClickOnce Security Settings]

Comment: If you don't use ClickOnce, you might also want to clean up the csproj file itself. The property groups `ManifestKeyFile` and `GenerateManifests` aren't needed. Same goes for the `app.manifest` file

Comment: 2019 user here. I think this got enabled for me when I tried to see what my options were for Publishing using the publish wizard. Somewhere along that line, it may have gotten checked.