# WPF Caliburn Micro Bootstrapper not found instance from another project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

Caliburn.Micro version 4.0.212.
Projects version .NET6

With Caliburn.Micro 3.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.2 it works

I am getting an error when I try to open a simple viewModel located in another project: "The component does not have a resource identified by the URI"
I am using the Caliburn Micro example: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/tutorals/WPF/Wpf.Tutorial

To reproduce the error I created another project to the solution: "CommonView"
I moved AboutViewModel from the main project to this one as I show in the image below:

[Solution Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bazgu.png)

In the bootstrapper I need to modify the SelectAssemblies method to add the files from this new project

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
         {
             var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
             assemblies.AddRange(base.SelectAssemblies());

             string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

             foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
             {
                 if (!fileName.Contains(".conf") && fileName.Contains("CommonView.dll"))
                 {
                     assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(fileName));
                 }
             }

             return assemblies;
         }
```

Now, when I call the About class from the button, Caliburn tries to get the instance, but it is not found so I get the error.

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
          {
                var instance = _container.GetInstance(service, key);    
                //instance is null
                return instance;
          }
```

However if I debug when CategoryViewModel is called, it returns the instance correctly

I saw this post where Juan Carlos overrides InitializeComponent(), but I think It should have a easier aproachment: [The component does not have a resource identified by the uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646331/the-component-does-not-have-a-resource-identified-by-the-uri)

Thank you in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the loading of the assembly, which should be like this
assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName));

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suzcook/loadfile-vs-loadfrom

Live long and prosper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).