# Need to understand Log4Net Configuration section WebForm

Tags: asp.net, log4net

i was thinking to use Log4Net for our webform application in asp.net. so i checked few article on this but i saw all article not saying about each property regarding configuration.

so i apologized that i have to paste bit big config section here and looking for some one who can help me to understand each property usage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DbAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="0" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="{auto}" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log4Net ([date],[thread],[level],[logger],[message],[exception]) VALUES 
         (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%t" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="10" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%p" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="1000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%c" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%m" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="DbAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

please see the above config details and answer each property.
1) why `<bufferSize value="0" />` is set to 0 ? when one should set other value to `bufferSize` property ?

2) `<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />`
how do i know what `PublicKeyToken` value i need to use.

3) what is the meaning of connection string auto `<connectionString value="{auto}" />` ?

4)

what is the meaning of **conversionPattern**   or

5 what is **ExceptionLayout** `<layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />`

6) what is the meaning of below xml

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="DbAppender" />
</root>
```

what is `RollingFileAppender` ?
what is `DbAppender` ?

please discuss about my each point & question. thanks

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ `bufferSize <= 1` means no buffering. Log is written instantly to the database.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.BufferSize.html

2/ `PublicKeyToken` is not Log4net related. Have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321419/what-is-the-role-of-public-key-token). Keep the given token.

3/ `{auto}` in connectionString seems to be custom code, maybe taken from [here](http://blog.gfader.com/2010/05/log4net-how-to-change-settings-of.html)

4/ [List of conversion patterns](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)

5/ Exception layout: only the exception text from the logging event will be logged.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout.html

6/ 
`FileAppender` -> log to file.
`RollingFileAppender` -> log to file with rotating logs (max N files of length L, then they are erased).
`DbAppender` -> log to database, that's why there is a connectionString.

More info: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: log4net has its own forum where i can ask question ?

Comment: what is the meaning of <conversionPattern 
value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" /> ? can u help me to understand this. thanks