# What is "publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35"?

Tags: windows, server, xml-parsing, unattended-processing, unattend-file

I am very curious to know what is this thing called "**publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35**" and where is that used for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on public key tokens. That being said, i think it's a publickeytoken of many dlls signed by Microsoft. Since they use the same pair of a private key and a public key, that results in publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35 appearing in many different dll references.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322775/3738722) can give you additional explanation.